# What's happening in Mexico in Robocop?

Tags: plot-explanation, robocop

In the 1987 *Robocop*, people mention the US army is helping the Mexican government fight rebel forces in what a news anchorman euphemistically refers to as 'the Mexican Crisis'.

What cause are these rebels fighting for, and why has the US sided against them?

Comment: We don't know, it's just scene setting and not relevant to the plot.

Comment: I'm sure it had something to do with noodles: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/NoodleIncident/CalvinAndHobbes

Comment: It's also worth noting the original Robocop was explicitly a [dystopian satire on 80s / Reagan-era US political trends taken to the extreme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCop#Thematic_analysis) - mostly domestic policy, but Cold War proxy wars were common where US special forces intervened overseas (e.g. [Grenada](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Grenada)) to tilt the balance in favour of the pro-US faction against the pro-USSR faction, so "US troops join proxy war, but in neighbouring Mexico" would fit that theme of "1980s but more so".

Comment: I think the writers were just employing the Two Rules For Success In Life: 1) Don’t tell all you know.

Answer (score 19):

> More fighting in the Mexican Crisis today when American troops participated in a Joint raid with Mexican Nationals against rebel racket positions in Cancun.

There's no more about that from drafts of the scripts or the movie transcript. Like many anticipation/SF movies, they set some background with big or small discrepancies between the two eras to back up the idea of it being in the future.

What these rebels are fighting isn't said. Why would the USA be helping the mexican government? Because it's common interest, as it's often the case when countries are involved, especially neighbours. This is not said either in the movie.

Comment: Of course, that could all be a smokescreen for a joint boondoggle to some Cancun resort, since at least in our reality it seems unlikely rebels would be positioned in _Cancun_ of all places.  (_Mostly_-kidding. But in the Robocop dystopia, it's not impossible. Then again, it's (probably more) possible that Cancun **isn't** a resort destination at all, in their world.)